# move first 12 characters of each line to the end of each line

Tags: notepad++

I want to move first string of each line to the end of each line and surround with brackets. I want this:

```
arctic_a0001 Author of the danger trail, Philip Steels, etc.
arctic_a0002 Not at this particular case, Tom, apologized Whittemore.
```

to be this:

```
Author of the danger trail, Philip Steels, etc. (arctic_a0001)
Not at this particular case, Tom, apologized Whittemore. (arctic_a0002)
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.{12})( )(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$3$2\($1\)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (.{12})       # group 1, 12 any characters
  ( )           # group 2, a space
  (.+)          # group 3, rest of the line
$
```

**Replacement:**

```
$3          # content of group 3
$2          # content of group 2
\(          # opening parenthese, have to be escaped in Notepad++
$1          # content of group 1
\)          # closing parenthese, have to be escaped in Notepad++
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]